# Is it possible to create something similar to WHERE NOT IN ( :values ) in Hibernate Search?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am actively searching through the Internet for solution to something that I know can be accomplished but I am frustrated why does it not work with Hibernate Search. What I am looking for is something similar to SQL clause `where not in (1,2,3)`

I have two entities, A and B.

```
@Indexed
public class A
{
   @Field
   public String field1;
   @FieldBridge(impl = LongBridge.class)
   public Long field2;
   @IndexEmbedded
   public Set<B> names;
}

public class B {
   @Field
   public String field3;
   @ContainedIn
   public Set<A> names2;
}
```

I am positively running search using querybuilder which looks like this:

```
queryBuilder.keyword()
                .fuzzy()
                .onFields("field1", "names.field3", "field2")
                .matching(matching+"-field2:(1 2 3)")
                .createQuery();
```

But `matching` does not read this as full Lucene matching pattern I think. It returns values that have `field2` set to `1 2 3` instead of filtering those documents out.

EDIT1:
I have found boolean query builder to be helpfull, I have created query with call to `not()` expecting it to filter the data. The underlying lucene query is what I expected, the same as I wrote in the first approach, but the lucene still returns wrong values. On the other hand Luke tool for lucene indexes queries with this expression returns what I am expecting.

EDIT2:
What I was doing wrong is that I used single query and concatinated values, while each value of the `field2` should have been carried by another boolean junction. It wokrs great now!

What do I do wrong? Should I use another mechanism? Is it even supported by Hibernate Search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `.keyword()...matching( ... )` is not a query that accepts special characters. This method expects to be passed plain text. You cannot use `-` or `:` in there.

If all this content is passed directly by users and you do need something that accepts operators, have a look at [`simpleQueryString()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_simple_query_string_queries).

If instead the filter is provided by yourself, the developer, just use the [`bool` query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_combining_queries).

In your case:

```java
Query includedQuery = queryBuilder.keyword()
                .fuzzy()
                .onFields("field1", "names.field3", "field2")
                .matching(matching)
                .createQuery();

BooleanJunction<?> combinedQueryBuilder = querybuilder.bool();
combinedQueryBuilder.must(includedQuery);
for (String excluded : Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3")) {
    combinedQueryBuilder.mustNot(queryBuilder.keyword()
                .fuzzy()
                .onField("field2")
                .matching(excluded)
                .createQuery());
}

Query combinedQuery = combinedQueryBuilder.createQuery();
```